# Align the various elements of a bootstrap touchSpin

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have the elements of my bootstrap touchSpin well aligned as in the demo (http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin).

As you can see in the example below, the two buttons are vertically well aligned with the text box.

[image]

In my case, the minus button, the plus button and the text box are not well aligned.

[image]

To show explicitely my problem, I have uploaded a demo on http://www.finapp.biz/testabcd/

Do you have any idea on how I could solve this problem?

I hope my question is understandable.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a bootstrap component called Button addons, you can read more about them [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-segmented) at the official Bootsrap page.
I'll leave you a code snippet that looks like the item you are looking for.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">L</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">R</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```